# Sending passwords through GET request

Tags: asp.net, rest, asp.net-core

I have an app that requires users to enter database passwords. These passwords will not be saved on the server, and the server does not need to remember anything about the database after the request. If it's my understanding, most web servers will log get requests, and the browser can as well (does it do this even for fetch() requests?). I do not want to put databases at risk, but I also understand that you should not use a body in GET requests.

I am also not creating resources, so from what I also understand, I should not be using a POST request. Is there a safe way to send a get request with the password (over https) that makes sure it is not logged on the server? This would be an app that anyone could start - so I have no idea what their server configuration could be so I couldn't specifically disable it on one server to ignore it.

Comment: Use a POST request.

Comment: Put the credentials in a custom HTTP header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> so from what I also understand, I should not be using a POST request.

Your understanding is incorrect. `POST` is the appropriate verb when none of the other verbs make sense. From [the spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.3):

> The POST method requests that the target resource process the representation enclosed in the request according to the resource's own specific semantics.

Put simply, that means POST does whatever the service says it does. It isn't [safe](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.1), [idempotent](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.2), or [cacheable](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.3) so there are disadvantages to just using it for everything, but the intent is for it to be the catch-all verb.

You should not use `GET` because, as you mentioned, you should not include a body and URLs often get logged, which would expose your credentials.

Answer (score 1):

If the client for your app is going to be a browser you can just use https only cookies to handle the authentication flow. In case if you want it to extend or use it in any other type of client, you can use the  [Authorization HTTP header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization).